# How to create Map from Hibernate query list

Tags: hibernate, list, dictionary, criteria

I have a requirement to create Map from Hibernate query result. Here is what I need

The query returns list of users. I have to create a map from the list. The map key will be dept id and the map value will be list of users for that department.

Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(user.class).list

This will return `List[user1, user2,...]`

I want to create map from the list

```
Map< dept1:[user1,user2,user3,..],
    dept2:[user1,user2,user3,..],
    ..
    ..
   >
```

Is there any easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Map collection feature of hibernate. But, you may have to query for each department(sort of loop) and add it to the final Map.

Check the Map section in the [document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-indexed) .